# insert data into a database from ajax success request

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I want to insert data into a database from a successful ajax request div

I want to insert data into a database from a successful ajax request div
I have called ajax using a generated id from a database now what I want to do is I want to submit data into a table using the ajax success variables into another table.

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input type="hidden" name="clientID" value="<?php echo $clientID;?>">
                <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" name="name" required="" placeholder="RIDER NAME">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user form-control-feedback"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="phone_number" placeholder="PHONE NUMBER" autocomplete="off">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone-alt form-control-feedback"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="IMEI" placeholder="IMEI NUMBER" autocomplete="off">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone form-control-feedback"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
                  <div class="col-xs-6">
                  </div>
                  <!-- /.col -->
                  <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat" name="register_rider">Register Rider</button>
                    <br/>
                  </div>
                  <!-- /.col -->
                </div>
              </form>
```

this does the ajax request

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){

         $(document).on('click', '#getUser', function(e){

          e.preventDefault();

    var uid = $(this).attr("data-id");   // it will get id of clicked row

    $('#debtor').html(''); // leave it blank before ajax call
    $('#mySidenav').show();      // load ajax loader

    $.ajax({
      url: 'getClientDetails.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: 'id='+uid,
      dataType: 'html'
    })
    .done(function(data){
      console.log(data);  
      $('#debtor').html('');    
      $('#debtor').html(data); // load response 
      $('#modal-loader').hide();      // hide ajax loader 
    })
    .fail(function(){
      $('#debtor').html('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></i> Something went wrong, Please try again...');
      $('#modal-loader').hide();
    });

  });

       });

     </script>
```

// here is getClientDetails.php

```
<?php
include_once('config/dbconfig.php');



$sql = "SELECT * FROM clients WHERE id=:id";
//Prepare your SELECT statement.
$statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
//The Primary Key of the row that we want to select.
$id = intval($_REQUEST['id']);
//I highly recomment not to use $_REQUEST, use $_GET or even better $_POST

//Bind our value to the paramater :id.
$statement->bindValue(':id', $id);

//Execute our SELECT statement.
$statement->execute();

//Fetch the row.
$row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$full_name= $row['full_name'];
$user_name = $row['user_name'];
$phone = $row['phone'];
$IMEI = $row['IMEI'];
$latitude = $row['latitude'];
$longitude = $row['longitude'];
$email = $row['email'];
$clientID = $row['id'];



if (!empty($_POST['register_rider'])){
    $clientID = trim($_POST['clientID']);
    $clientID = strip_tags($clientID);
    $clientID = htmlspecialchars($clientID);

    $name = trim($_POST['name']);
    $name = strip_tags($name);
    $name = htmlspecialchars($name);

    $phone_number = trim($_POST['phone_number']);
    $phone_number = strip_tags($phone_number);
    $phone_number = htmlspecialchars($phone_number);

    $IMEI = trim($_POST['IMEI']);
    $IMEI = strip_tags($IMEI);
    $IMEI = htmlspecialchars($IMEI);




 $stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO drivers (clientID, name, phone_number, IMEI)VALUES(:clientID, :name, :phone_number, :IMEI)');

 $stmt->bindParam(':clientID', $clientID);
 $stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);
 $stmt->bindParam(':phone_number', $phone_number);
 $stmt->bindParam(':IMEI', $IMEI);





 if($stmt->execute()){
    ?>
    <script>
      alert("Rider Added successfully");
    </script>
    <?php
    header( "refresh:5;url=clies.php" );
  }
  else{
    ?>
    <script>
      alert("Couldn't add rider");
    </script>
    <?php
  }



}

?>
```

What I want to do is insert the data into the database but  is not working although the isset post is valid, no errors too...

Comment: "not working" does not give us much to go on, you should be able to debug it more than that.

Comment: **DON'T** call `strip_tags` or `htmlspecialchars` on input like this. It damages things and makes your life miserable when it comes to escaping for other contexts like CSV, JSON or email. Instead of baking it out as HTML, keep it raw and escape *if and when* you're displaying it using the *appropriate escaping method*. Since you're using placeholder values () there's no need to worry about SQL injection here, not that either of these methods provide any protection from that, just that some people mistakenly believe they do.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a success clause to your jQuery ajax code block under the dataType line.

```
        success: function(data)
        {   

        }
```

From there it's probably easiest to just do a second Ajax request to a PHP page which will add the necessary data for you.